# Using printf command in bash

Tags: bash

```
#hello world in bash

s="hello world"
printf "%s\n" $s
```

I expected the output to be `hello world\n` but it is `hello\nworld\n`

can anyone explain this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word ["word splitting"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting). The expansion of the `$s` variable is then split into words and `printf` sees two arguments and uses them individually.

Quote your variable expansion to prevent this (the way you did your variable assignment):

```
s="hello world"
printf '%s\n' "$s"
```